# python pandas describe groupby output question

Tags: pandas, output, structure, describe

I use describe with groupby on a dataframe such as:

```
df_stats = df[["x","y"]].describe(df["key1"],df["key2"])
```

this produces the standard set of stats for "x" and "y: in df by key/key2 value combinations.  these combinations are, in general, not know a priori.

if I print df_stats it will list the various combinations of key1/key2 values as row values but I
cannot find out where these combination values are being stored (should be in the df_stats dataframe, no?)

the objective is to be able to have other dataframe data to "look up" data in the df_stats rows so as to include it in calculations - appreciate any insights in advance - pulling my hair out

thx - j

Comment: did you try df_stats = df[["x","y"]].describe()

Comment: y   -unrelated to iaaue - it gens stats for entire df.  using groupby produces stats by gorpus within the df.  the output produces a matrix of the stats where the rows are grp value combinations and the columns are defined by a combination of variable and particular stat.

if i print that stat output the row stats are identified by group keys value combinations
but these are not part of the describe output matrix/dataframe.  so the describe process
is creating a series somehwere with the unique combination of group key values but
the describe process doew not make it readily available.